# FMDB with multithread problem

Tags: ios, fmdb

In my ios app, I use FMDB to connect to the sqlite3 db.
In the app, db will be used in multithread.As a result, I create a singleton in this way:

```
+ (id)instance
{
static DBManager *dbManager = nil;
if (dbManager == nil) {
    dbManager = [[DBManager alloc]init];
}

[dbManager initialDBmanager];
return dbManager;
}
```

however Error: FMDataBase is currently in use , sometimes occures.
then I update the instance:

```
+ (id)instance
{
static DBManager *dbManager = nil;
if (dbManager == nil) {
    dbManager = [[DBManager alloc]init];
            [dbManager initialDBmanager];
}

while([dbManager.db inUse])//In my opinion this promises the db is free
    {
    }
return dbManager;
}
```

The Error still exists.
So My question is how to correctly create a singleton and why the code can't avoid the error.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use @synchronized, and it temporarily fixs the problem.

I will keep eyes on it~

Comment: where you used @synthesized?

Comment: Now I add a `nslock` for each write action to db. `synthesized` is a lazy way~:-)